# разбивка чисел на разряды в калькуляторе на js

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как разбить число которое вводится в input на разряды так чтобы она работала с математическими операциями. Сейчас калькулятор работает нормально. Когда разбиваю число перестает работать. Выдает NaN.

Вот функция которая разбивает числа на разряды.

```
function discharge(){
  $('input').val(String($('input').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'')).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "));
}
discharge();
$('input').keyup(function(){
  discharge();
});
```

Comment: Инпут хранит все как строку. Перед операциями нужно "убирать" разбиение и превращать строку в число.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `discharge()` в вашем коде производит замену всех символов, кроме цифр и точки, на пустую строку. Затем она форматирует строку ввода, добавляя пробелы между каждыми тремя цифрами с помощью регулярного выражения.

Чтобы использовать число, в котором разделителем является точка, в математических операциях, нужно удалить пробелы из строки и заменить точку на десятичный разделитель

Вы можете модифицировать функцию `discharge()` следующим образом, чтобы она возвращала правильный формат числа:

```
function discharge() {
  const inputVal = $('input').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g,''); // удаляем все символы, кроме цифр и точки
  const decimalSeparator = Number("1.2").toLocaleString().substring(1,2); // определяем десятичный разделитель, используемый в локали
  const formattedVal = inputVal.replace(".", decimalSeparator) // заменяем точку на десятичный разделитель
                               .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "); // форматируем строку ввода
  $('input').val(formattedVal);
  return Number(formattedVal.replace(/\s/g, '')); // удаляем пробелы из строки и возвращаем число
}
```

Теперь вы можете использовать значение, возвращаемое функцией `discharge()`, в математических операциях

```js
const x = discharge();
const y = discharge();
const z = x + y;
console.log(z); // отобразит сумму x и y, разделенную на разряды
```

Кроме того, вам нужно изменить обработчик событий `keyup`, чтобы он вызывал функцию `discharge()` только после того, как пользователь закончил вводить число. Для этого вы можете использовать задержку, например, 500 миллисекунд, перед вызовом функции `discharge()`

```
let timeout;
$('input').keyup(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    discharge();
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Не сработала ) Но спасибо за ответ